# PHP preformatted output by default

Tags: php, var-dump

Is there a php.ini setting (or some other setting) that will cause print_r and var_dump output to be automatically formatted as though I had explicitly placed a `<pre>` tag before such an output statement?

Comment: The output of those functions *is* automatically formatted. Your problem is that you're viewing that output in a *browser*, which destroys the formatting...

Comment: But I've seen it done, so I know it's possible to have the browser show desired formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do this within PHP but I know [xdebug replaces PHP's normal var_dump](http://xdebug.org/docs/display) and it looks pretty awesome.

---

Here's an example

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->xdebug = 'http://www.xdebug.org/';
$object->vardump = 'Looks awesome now';

$int = 1;
$str = 'Stack Overflow';
$array = array(0 => 'foo', 1 => 'bar', '2' => 'baz');

var_dump($object);
var_dump($int);
var_dump($str);
var_dump($array);
```

results in

[image]

Comment: I have xdebug and phpstorm running with php.  When running the test script from the link you provided, the results are:array(4) { ["one"]=> string(23) "a somewhat long string!" ["two"]=> array(1) { ["two.one"]=> array(2) { ["two.one.zero"]=> int(210) ["two.one.one"]=> array(2) { ["two.one.one.zero"]=> float(3.141592564) ["two.one.one.one"]=> float(2.7) } } } ["three"]=> object(test)#1 (3) { ["pub"]=> *RECURSION* ["priv":"test":private]=> bool(true) ["prot":protected]=> int(42) } ["four"]=> array(6) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(2) [3]=> int(3) [4]=> int(4) [5]=> int(5) } }

Comment: Looks just like that on my browser (firefox) output -- all mushed together on one line.  ???

Comment: @tgoneil Try `xdebug_var_dump()`?  There are also a few ini settings discussed in the link.

Comment: I just now tried it by running xdebug_var_dump instead of var_dump and it's still all on one line.  ???

Comment: @tgoneil Then I suggest you check out the 'Related Settings' for the display xdebug documentation.  It appears your configuration may not be setup properly.

Comment: Looking over the info, it says xdebug.overload_var_dump is the default.  Just for grins I added xdebug.overload_var_dump=1 to php.ini, then restarted apache.  Still no dice.  ???

Comment: @tgoneil I'm not sure, I would post a new question as to why your xdebug might not be outputting var_dump as you expect.

Comment: Ok found the problem.  Amazingly, the info was indeed found in the XDebug documentation about html_errors setting.  Turns out my php.ini file had html_errors=Off.  Changed it On and voila!  THANK YOU CHARLES!!!